# my filtered list item opens wrong activity

Tags: android

i added textBox to my app to filter the ListView items, so when i type a text in textBox it filter normally but when i try to select that filtered item it opens the activity of the original position before the filter rather than the one on the filtered posttion.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

 inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

 String[] ciwaananadaGabayada = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gabayada_array);
 mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 // Adding items to listview
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.gabay_item, ciwaananadaGabayada);
 mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

 //Enabling Search Filter
 inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
   // When user changed the text
   MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   //adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

  }


  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

  }
 });

 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


         switch (position) {
             case 0:
                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Xuseenow_caqligu.class);
                 startActivity(newActivity);
                 break;

             case 1:
                 Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dhurwaa_adhiga.class);
                 startActivity(newActivity1);
                 break;

             case 2:
                 Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), xuseenowAqoonXume.class);
                 startActivity(newActivity2);
                 break;
```

Comment: put your adapter class

Comment: @CoDFather where do i put my adapter class

Comment: put it here!!!!

Comment: @CoDFather i dont have an adaper class at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using position in `OnItemClickListener` suppose your list have 3 elements and when you filter list  and your list shown one item and then you click on that item the position in this case is same rather its actual position in non filter list list is 3 or 2 so you always get 0 position  in this case.

For this you need to get DataItem of filtered list by using position which you have  and then check which activity you want to open for  what value you have in DataItem.

Comment: please can you give your answer detailed?

Comment: Do not use position  in switch case. You should get data item of selected position and then compare  with  your  appropriate  Activity which you want to open.

Comment: please show me how to get data item of selected position.